# When you can't change the girl, change the girl

Tags: punctuation

How can one differentiate between these two "Girl"? I mean I was not able to understand the sentence first is there any sort of punctuation missing in this sentence?

> Just want to clarify my intention is not to offend and these are not my words. I just want to learn.

Comment: If you can't change the girl (this change means: लड़की को बदल नही सकते), change the girl (this change means लड़की बदल डालो). The first change is changing her nature/characters...and if you can't do it, go for the second change which is 'changing the girl herself!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between "the girl" and "the girl".   There is a difference between "change" and "change".   The first means something like *alter* or *transform*.   The second means something like *trade* or *replace*.

That being said, I find it more natural to mark that difference by changing the number of the direct object.   I would phrase that sentiment in this way:

> If you can't change the girl, change girls.

Social implication aside, there's nothing wrong with the original sentence.   The second sense of "change" doesn't require a plural object.   The singular is common enough in phrases like "change the light bulb", despite the fact that there must be at least two bulbs involved in that exchange.

Without context, the original sentence could mean either:

> When you can't transform the girl, replace her.

or

> When you can't replace the girl, transform her.

Unlike my paraphrasing, there is nothing in the original to show which sense of "change" belongs in each place.   The only thing that marks that there are two senses of "change" in that sentence is the contrast between them.   There have to be separate senses for one to still be possible while the other is impossible.

I assume that the original means "if you can't transform her, replace her" because [there are plenty of fish in the sea](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There+are+plenty+of+fish+in+the+sea) but [a leopard can't change its spots](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/A+leopard+can%27t+change+its+spots).

Answer (score 2):

IMO, it means "if you can not change the girl, then you should switch to another girl."

Comment: Yes eventually I got the same meaning but my question is what is there in the sentence which makes your opinion so?

Comment: @Jeet contex determines, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Agree, so context is the only thing which makes the sentence clear?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a punctuation problem. This is a play on two different meanings of the verb change. In [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/change) the meanings are

> 2. (transitive, ergative) To make something into something different. 
>      *The fairy changed the frog into a prince.   I had to change the wording of the ad so it would fit.*
> 3. (transitive) To replace.
>      *Ask the janitor to come and change the lightbulb.   After a brisk walk, I washed up and changed my shirt.*

The sentence means, "When you can't make the girl into the kind of girl you want, replace the girl." It's the same girl, different change.

And someone could legitimately be insulted (in my opinion) by being viewed as transformable and/or interchangeable.

Comment: Thank you for the description, Just want to clarify my intention is not to offend and these are not my words. I just wanted to learn.